# How to join Aspnet_User to my custom user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a `User` model object and I wan't to when I get this object to get `aspnet_User` object with it for additional data (`usename` etc.)

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid UserId_fk { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public virtual AspnetUsers AspnetUsers { get; set; } 

    }

public class AspnetUsers
    {
        public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
        public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    }
```

In database `UserId_fk`  is `FK to aspnet_Users.UserId`.
How to map this?

Comment: In the table (class) `User`, I used to have the UserId which is used by the asp.net membership authentication so basically the same as what you did, so just query Users where UserId equals to some value...

Comment: Can you provide some code example? Just to note I wan't to use this as a navigation property. When I call User object I wan't AspnetUser to be loaded with it.

Comment: I use `User.UserId_fk` to reference `aspnet_Users` table just to join them. But I wan't to user `int UserId` (AI column) for other joins. I don't want to use GUID in all tables as a references.

Comment: @1110 you mean *want* or *won't* ? And what is type of association? Both ends required, or not?

Comment: Want. 1:1 when user register through asp membership I add it to Users also. I read something now and I see that this is maybe bad thing to do. I consider to make view that gets data from aspnet_Users but I never did something like this and don't know how to map view in EF.